# Use JFuzzyLogic and android app

Tags: android, fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

hello i want to use [JFuzzyLogic](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/index.html) into my app Android; i have 2 questions:

1. JFuzzyLogic use antlrworks-1.2.jar, jcommon-1.0.14.jar, jfreechart-1.0.11.jar; (for me is pointless) but it can be a problem for google play store?
2. JFuzzyLogic weighs 8 mb, there is a way to reduce the time upload into debug?
   thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jfuzzylite instead. It is free and open source. It does not require third-party libraries, contains more features than jfuzzylogic (except for parameter optimization), and the binary size is less than 300KB. Visit www.fuzzylite.com.